# Envelope distort effect warps shape but not pattern fill-illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, patterns

I am in the middle of following a tutorial on making a pattern tile. I have created a pattern and now filled it in a box. I now want to warp it going to object>envelope distort>make with warp. In the tutorial both the shape and the pattern have the warp effect applied. Mine however only distorts the shape.

- Scale strokes and effects has been ticked
- Align to pixel grid has been ticked

These are what is selected in the transform side drop down menu.

[image]

This is the intended output

[image]

And this is what happens when I apply the effect

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object > Envelope Distort > Envelope Options`

Make certain the `Distort Appearance` and `Distort Pattern Fills` options are checked there.

Simple pattern of horizontal lines....

[image]